# Creating data.frame column with elements depending on two other columns (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

Before, I asked this question: [Moving certain elements of data frame into new columns (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252047/moving-certain-elements-of-data-frame-into-new-columns-in-r)

Now, I have the same data frame:

```
   > jiz <- data.frame(Type=c("X","B","B","B","B","X","B"),
+                   Action=c("both","1","2","2","1","both","1"))
> jiz
  Type Action
1    X   both
2    B      1
3    B      2
4    B      2
5    B      1
6    X   both
7    B      1
```

I would like to construct *one* new column, called "Result" with three values, "X", "Y" and "Z", depending on values from both columns "Type" and "Action".

If Type is 'X' and Action is 'both' --> "Result" is X

If Type is 'B' and Action is '1'    --> "Result" is Y

If Type is 'B' and Action is '2'    --> "Result" is Z,

such that new data frame becomes:

```
> jiz.new
  Type Action Result
1    X   both      X
2    B      1      Y
3    B      2      Z
4    B      2      Z
5    B      1      Y
6    X   both      X
7    B      1      Y
```

The transform + ifelse, from the post I linked to above, does not work for me here, because I have more than two combinations going into/creating *the same* new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a function:

```
conditionalResult <- function(argtype, argaction){
if (argtype=="X" & argaction=="both")
  return("X")
if (argtype=="B" & argaction==1)
  return("Y")
if (argtype=="B" & argaction==2)
  return("Z")
```

After function definition convert your data to data.table:

```
install.packages("data.table")
require("data.table")
jiz <- as.data.table(jiz)
```

And create a new conditional column:

```
jiz[, c("Result"):=conditionalResult(Type, Action)]
```

Voila, now you have new column called Result in your data.table with corresponding values.

Comment: Or if you don't want to use data.table, use jiz$Result<-sapply(jiz$Type, conditionalResult, argaction=jiz$Action)

Comment: Using the data frame method, which is what I want, I get this:

{> jiz$Result<-sapply(jiz$Type, conditionalResult, argaction=jiz$Action)
There were 17 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In if (argtype == "X" & argaction == "both") return("X") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (argtype == "X" & argaction == "both") return("X") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used}

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the second argument being a vector

Comment: mapply(conditionalResult,Type, Action) works better.